# How to execute CRM workflow when a record is shared

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there any way to execute a CRM workflow when a record is shared to a user or team in CRM 2015 online?

Comment: What do you want the workflow do?

Comment: I want to secure the share point document folder based on the shared user/team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick a plugin to [fire on share](http://howto-mscrm.com/2012/07/how-to-series-11-how-to-trigger-plugin.html). Prob OOTB, there is no way to register a workflow to trigger on share (today anyway I think).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without development AFAIK. To do that with development you will have to develop a plugin that will handle GrantAccess/ModifyAccess/RemoveAccess message.